# How do I wake up the printer when it sleeps?

Tags: 12.04, printing, ltsp

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on an LTSP network.

I have attached a printer to the server via USB.

The printer is an HP LaserJet Pro P1102 with driver Foomatic/foo2zjs-z2 (recommended).

Often the printer goes to sleep, and then jobs submitted do not get printed. Even when the printer is turned on to force waking.

How can I wake up the printer so the print jobs will be executed?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with HP P1102 and CUPS server and here is what I did. Open your server terminal (I assume CUPS has been already installed and P1102 hooked up in one of your server USB ports). In terminal enter:

```
lsusb
```

You should see the following for your HP P1102:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID XXXX:XXXX HP, Inc LaserJet P1102
```

The first XXXX is your Vendor ID and second XXXX is your Product ID.

Then create a file:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-printer.rules
```

And insert the following (change XXXXs relevant to your values from lsusb output):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="XXXX", ATTRS{idProduct}=="XXXX", MODE:="774", GROUP="lp"
```

Safe the file and reload udev rules:

```
sudo udevadm control —reload-rules
```

Now CUPS will be able to wake up your printer next time you start using it.

Answer (score 2):

Type

```
cupsenable printername
```

in konsole

Comment: Works for me. Upvote. Wandering why someone downvoted this.